# ember modal dialog wont close

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have used ember-modal-dialog. I have set the modal to close (as per the example on git - https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog). But it does not close when I click the background.

application.hbs

```
{{#if isShowingModal}}
  {{#modal-dialog close="toggleModal" targetAttachment="center" translucentOverlay=true}}
      abc
  {{/modal-dialog}}
{{/if}}
```

applications.js

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    isShowingModal: false,
    actions: {
        showNavMenu: function() {
          this.toggleProperty('isShowingModal');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are triggering "`toggleModal`" function on clicking close button of model. as your code you define `showNavMenu` function to toggle the property `isShowingModal`
your code should be close = "showNavMenu" so on click close button this function called and model close properly.
correct code is

```
{{#if isShowingModal}}
  {{#modal-dialog close="showNavMenu" targetAttachment="center" translucentOverlay=true}}
      abc
  {{/modal-dialog}}
{{/if}}
```

or change the function name in controller from `showNavMenu` to `toggleModal`